# How to fix Input was not in correct format in reader.Read() part when there is rows returned?

Tags: c#, mysql, datareader

I am encountering a problem in the reader.Read() part of my code, says that input was not in correct format, but there is a row returned since the reader.HasRows returns true..

I have also searched in google about this and learned that the conversion might be the problem. However, this might not be the problem for me since the code worked before, and now I am encountering this.

How is this possible? What could be the problem? Thanks in advance..

Here is the stack trace:
StackTrace  "   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)\r\n   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)\r\n   at MySql.Data.Types.MySqlInt32.MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.ReadValue(MySqlPacket packet, Int64 length, Boolean nullVal)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadColumnValue(Int32 index, MySqlField field, IMySqlValue valObject)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.ReadColumnData(Boolean outputParms)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.NextRow(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Read()\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbEnumerator.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView.get_Items()" string

Here is my code:

```
class ControlDB
    {
        MySqlConnection connection;
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
        MySqlCommand command;
        DataTable dataTable;
        MySqlDataReader reader;

        private string server;
        private string database;
        private string userid;
        private string password;

        public ControlDB()
        {
            ConnectDB();
        }
        public void ConnectDB()
        {
            server = "localhost";
            database = "YBHDB";
            userid = "root";
            password = "";

            string connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + userid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
        }
 public string[] GetCustomer(string arrivalDate, string arrivalTime, string departureDate, string departureTime, string roomId)
        {
            string[] customer = new string[20];
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            stringBuilder.Append("SELECT c.FirstName, c.MiddleName, c.LastName, c.Address, c.Nationality, c.ContactNumber, c.Email, c.CustomerID, rc.RoomId, rc.RCID, rc.ArrivalDate, rc.DepartureDate, rc.ArrivalTime, rc.DepartureTime, rc.DaysOfStay, rc.NumberOfAdult, rc.NumberOfChildren, rc.PaymentType, rc.CardType, rc.CardNumber ");
            stringBuilder.Append("FROM customer c JOIN reservationcheckin rc ON ");
            stringBuilder.Append("c.CustomerId = rc.CustomerID ");
            stringBuilder.Append("WHERE ((concat(rc.ArrivalDate, ' ', rc.ArrivalTime) BETWEEN concat(@arrivalDT, ' ', @arrivalTM) AND concat(@departureDT, ' ', @departureTM) ");
            stringBuilder.Append("OR concat(rc.DepartureDate, ' ', rc.DepartureTime) BETWEEN concat(@arrivalDT, ' ', @arrivalTM) AND concat(@departureDT, ' ', @departureTM)) ");
            stringBuilder.Append("OR (concat(@arrivalDT, ' ', @arrivalTM) BETWEEN concat(rc.ArrivalDate, ' ', rc.ArrivalTime) AND concat(rc.DepartureDate, ' ', rc.DepartureTime) ");
            stringBuilder.Append("OR concat(@departureDT, ' ', @departureTM) BETWEEN concat(rc.ArrivalDate, ' ', rc.ArrivalTime)  AND concat(rc.DepartureDate, ' ', rc.DepartureTime)) ) ");
            stringBuilder.Append("AND rc.RoomId = @roomId");



            command = new MySqlCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = stringBuilder.ToString();


            MySqlParameter arrivalDateParameter = new MySqlParameter("@arrivalDT", Convert.ToDateTime(arrivalDate).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            MySqlParameter arrivalTimeParameter = new MySqlParameter("@arrivalTM", (Convert.ToDateTime(arrivalTime).TimeOfDay).ToString().Replace('{', ' ').Trim());
            MySqlParameter departureDateParameter = new MySqlParameter("@departureDT", Convert.ToDateTime(departureDate).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            MySqlParameter departureTimeParameter = new MySqlParameter("@departureTM", (Convert.ToDateTime(departureTime).TimeOfDay).ToString().Replace('{', ' ').Trim());
            MySqlParameter roomParameter = new MySqlParameter("@roomId", Convert.ToInt32(roomId));


            command.Parameters.Add(arrivalDateParameter);
            command.Parameters.Add(arrivalTimeParameter);
            command.Parameters.Add(departureDateParameter);
            command.Parameters.Add(departureTimeParameter);
            command.Parameters.Add(roomParameter);

           reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if(reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();
                customer[0] = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                customer[1] = reader["MiddleName"].ToString();
                customer[2] = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                customer[3] = reader["Address"].ToString();
                customer[4] = reader["Nationality"].ToString();
                customer[5] = reader["ContactNumber"].ToString();
                customer[6] = reader["Email"].ToString();
                customer[7] = reader["RoomID"].ToString();
                customer[8] = reader["ArrivalDate"].ToString();
                customer[9] = reader["ArrivalTime"].ToString();
                customer[10] = reader["DepartureDate"].ToString();
                customer[11] = reader["DepartureTime"].ToString();
                customer[12] = reader["DaysOfStay"].ToString();
                customer[13] = reader["NumberOfAdult"].ToString();
                customer[14] = reader["NumberOfChildren"].ToString();
                customer[15] = reader["PaymentType"].ToString();
                customer[16] = reader["CardType"].ToString();
                customer[17] = reader["CardNumber"].ToString();
                customer[18] = reader["CustomerID"].ToString();
                customer[19] = reader["RCID"].ToString();
            }
            reader.Close();

            return customer;
        }
}
```

Here is the method that is calling the GetCustomer():

```
   private void buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;

            string[] customer = new string[20];

            string roomId = button.Text.Split(' ')[1];

            customer = control.GetCustomer(arrivalDatePicker.Value.ToShortDateString(), arrivalTimePicker.Value.ToShortTimeString(), departureDatePicker.Value.ToShortDateString(), departureTimePicker.Value.ToShortTimeString(), roomId);

            firstNameText.Text = customer[0];
            middleNameText.Text = customer[1];
            lastNameText.Text = customer[2];
            addressText.Text = customer[3];
            nationalityText.Text = customer[4];
            contactText.Text = customer[5];
            emailText.Text = customer[6];
            roomNo.Text = customer[7];
            arrivalDatePicker.Text = customer[8];
            arrivalTimePicker.Text = customer[9];
            departureDatePicker.Text = customer[10];
            departureTimePicker.Text = customer[11];
            daysStay.Text = customer[12];
            numAdultText.Text = customer[13];
            numChildText.Text = customer[14];
            paymentTypeSelect.Text = customer[15];
            cardTypeSelect.Text = customer[16];
            cardNumberText.Text = customer[17];
            customerID = Convert.ToInt32(customer[18]);
            roomID = Convert.ToInt32(customer[7]);
            rcid = Convert.ToInt32(customer[19]);
        }
```

Comment: What line of code does this crash on? Can you post the line of code and the full exception stack trace? Also, instead of checking HasRows, you can just do a while (reader.Read()) { .... read your customer here .... }. I also recommend using a Customer class with all those properties, instead of using a 20 string array. It will make your code much cleaner and more maintainable.

Comment: @Jon Hello Jon, I've posted the stack trace.. Code is crashing on the reader.Read() itself..

Comment: check the type of your parameters, it's a type conversion exception

Comment: That stack trace is not even in your GetCustomer() method? Are you calling reader.Read() from a Debug immediate or watch window? Also your data types are all over the place. Why does your method Getcustomer() take roomId as a string, but you convert to an int in your SQL query? Why are your date parameters strings and being converted to datetime, then back to string?

Comment: Hello @Jon, how were you able to know that it's not from GetCustomer()? As for the date and time, textbox is returning a string, i need to get only the date or time part of each textbox.. so I formatted it using a string..

Comment: Because GetCustomer is not in the stack trace

Comment: Hello @Jon, I just got the stack trace when hovering in reader.Read(). Anyway, do you think that this has something to do with my parameter conversions? Since this has been working before..

Comment: @Jon, I also tried to get the exact query.. I tried not to use the parameters and used concatenation instead, and ran the query in sql it returns a row..

Comment: What happens when you use the hard-coded query in your code, instead of using the parameters?

Comment: @Jon, still encountered the same error when I hard-coded the query in the code..

Comment: Post all your code including the connection and connection string, as well as the values of the parameters. Thanks

Comment: Hello @Jon, I have updated my post.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Upon investigating, code was encountering an error in the time part. The datatype of arrivalTime and departureTime in SQL is Time, and when reader reads the rows issue is encountered there. So I just changed my datatype to varchar. Hopefully this won't cause any error in the future.. xx